# Teamcity Shared Library and Stash/Unstash Like Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, shared-libraries, teamcity

I am currently a jenkins user and is exploring the Teamcity.

In jenkins we have a concept of shared libraries, which basically extends a generic groovy code into different jenkins pipeline and avoid re-writing the same functionality in each jenkins file following the DRY (don't repeat yourself) , hide implementation complexity, keep pipelines short and easier to understand

### Example:

There could be a repository having all the Groovy functions like:

Repo: http:://github.com/DEVOPS/Utilities.git (repo Utilities)
Sample Groovy Scipt ==>> GitUtils.groovy with below functions

```
public void setGitConfig(String userName, String email) {
       sh "git config --global user.name ${userName}"
       sh "git config --global user.mail ${email}"
}



public void gitPush(StringbranchName) {
       sh "git push origin ${branchName}"
}
```

In jenkinsfile we can just call this function like below (of course we need to define config in jenkins for it to know the Repo url for Shared library and give it a name):

Pipeline

```
//name of shared library given in jenkins
@Library('utilities') _   

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage ('Example') {
            steps {
                // log.info 'Starting' 
                script { 
                     def gitutil = new GitUtils()
                     gitutils.setGitConfig("Ray", "Ray@rayban.com")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And that's it anyone wanting the same function has to just include the library in jenkinsfile and use it in pipeline

Questions:

1. Can we migrate over the same to Teamcity, if yes how can it be done? We do not want to spend lot of time to re-writing
2. Jenkins also support Stashing and unstashing of workspace between stages, is the similar concept present in teamcity?

   Example:

   ```
   pipeline {
      agent any
        stages {
           stage('Git checkout'){
               steps {  
                  stash includes: '/root/hello-world/*', name: 'mysrc'  
               }
           }
           stage('maven build'){
               agent { label 'slave-1' }
               steps {          
              unstash 'mysrc'
              sh label: '', script: 'mvn clean package'
               }
           }
       }   
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

As for reusing common TeamCity Kotlin DSL libraries, this can be done via maven dependencies. For that you have to mention it in the pom.xml file within your DSL code. You can also consider using JitPack if your DSL library code is hosted on GitHub for example and you do not want to handle building it separately and publishing its maven artifacts.

Although with migration from Jenkins to TeamCity you will most likely have to rewrite the common library (if you still need one at all), as TeamCity project model and DSL are quite different to what you have in Jenkins.

Speaking of stashing/unstashing workspaces, it may be covered by either artifact rules and artifact dependencies (as described here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/artifact-dependencies.html) or repository clone mirroring on agents.